# ckeditor image button and IE

Tags: internet-explorer, session, ckeditor

has anyone had any experience with this editor?

Ive been integrating this editor into a web application i am working on, and generally it has been going smoothely, except for one problem (is it a surprise that it involved IE?).

When the user clicks on the image button in anything except IE, every works as expected. When the user uses the image button in IE, it destroys their current session.

After a lot of painful hours of finding out exactly what it is doing, this is what ive found. When the user clicks on the image button, an iframe is loaded, and is directed the the index of the site. Now, the index of the site checks to see if the user has any sessions open, and if it does, it destroys it. And thus, the users session is getting destroyed. I found this out by taking out the session destroy on the index page, then ck works as expected....

So, i dont know if this is a problem with CK, or IE, but does anyone have suggestions for a workaround?

Let me know if you need more information.

Comment: Sounds like a CKeditor bug. Could you please tell us what version of IE you are using, and what operating system you are running it in? Also, are there any special security features enabled in IE?

Comment: It is happening in IE7 and 8. Ive tried reducing all security options in Ie to absolutely 0... but it is definitely the session being destroyed. The OS is opensuse, using apache as webserver and php for scripting.